# Update Twitter image and name after every login - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My users can login only by Twitter and I'm using the omniauth-twitter gem (https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter).
Rails 4.1.2 and Ruby 2.1.0

It works perfectly, the only problem is that whenever a user changes his profile photo or name, the database is not updated with the changes.

How can I make my app to see after every login if any of the attributes is changed and if so, to update the database with them?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add some code to your twitter callback action -- the action that is called by the path `/auth/twitter/callback` -- to read from the OmniAuth::AuthHash that is returned to you via `request.env['omniauth.auth']`. Basically, omniauth-twitter packages up the OAuth Provider's response into a convenient objet and places it in the request hash. So... something like this:

```
def twitter
  # ...
  update_picture
end

def update_picture
  auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  current_user.picture = auth.info.image
  # or whatever
end
```

FYI: The OmniAuth::AuthHash object is basically a hash with benefits. It is an instance of a [Hashie](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) object, in case you're interested in learning more. (Off the top of my head, I think it's a Mash hash.)

Also, you can find and example return response [here, in the omniauth-twitter readme](https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter#authentication-hash).